# How to do sliding window operation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, sequence

I have a following code

```
x=randi([1 150],1,400); 
d=max(x);
m=numel(x);
y=zeros(d,1);
p=zeros(d,d);
for k=1:m-1
y(x(k))=y(x(k))+1; 
p(x(k),x(k+1))=p(x(k),x(k+1))+1;
end
p=bsxfun(@rdivide,p,y);
p(isnan(p)) = 0; 
j=prod(p(p~=0));
[~,~,idx] = unique(x);
q=prod(hist(idx,1:max(idx))/numel(x));
s=log(j);
l=log(q);
g=s+l
```

In above code random no. generated from 1 to 150 with sequence length 400. finally I am getting output g,suppose random no. sequence generated by code is

```
x=[5,96,96,55,55,65,65,65,12,12,6,7,9,9,9,31,31,14,26,26,26,101,101,145,145,...]
```

so code is given output for whole sequence, but i want output for sliding window of size 10, i.e. o/p for sequence

```
[5,96,96,55,55,65,65,65,12,12],
```

then skipping 1st element and adding next element so window size should remain same, i.e.

```
[96,96,55,55,65,65,65,12,12,6],
```

then next for

```
[96,55,55,65,65,65,12,12,6,7],
```

likewise up to last, how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way, using for loop, is below code.

```
x=randi([1 150],1,12)

m=numel(x);
N=10;   %Window length

for n=0:m-N;

    y=x(1+n:N+n)

end
```

Full code will be below.

```
xr=randi([1 150],1,20)

z=numel(xr);
N=10;  %Window length


gAll=zeros(1,z-N+1);

for n=0:z-N;

    x=xr(1+n:N+n)

    d=max(x);
    m=numel(x);
    y=zeros(d,1);
    p=zeros(d,d);
    for k=1:m-1
    y(x(k))=y(x(k))+1; 
    p(x(k),x(k+1))=p(x(k),x(k+1))+1;
    end
    p=bsxfun(@rdivide,p,y);
    p(isnan(p)) = 0; 
    j=prod(p(p~=0));
    [~,~,idx] = unique(x);
    q=prod(hist(idx,1:max(idx))/numel(x));
    s=log(j);
    l=log(q);
    g=s+l

    gAll(n+1)=g;

end

plot(gAll)
```

Comment: I tried but I didn't got answer, can u post whole code so I can directly run.

Comment: I want figure that if gAll greater than -22 then it should be in red color and if less than -22 then should in blue color, how to do it

Comment: This is not related to your question. You can make another question in this site.

Comment: I am asking about above code that if gAll greater than -22 then it should be in red color and if less than -22 then it should in blue color

Comment: , I can not use matlab now. There are many persons who can help you in this site. Besides,  one question for one topic is a rule in this site.